# Java replacement of specific characters

Tags: java, string, replace

This is my first question on this site so i'll try not to be a total noob..

I'm currently creating hangman game in java.
So my question to you is if we are given a word "ghost"
and ghost is replaced with "_ ",

```
hiddenWord = ghost.length();
for (i=0; i < ghost.lenth(); i ++)
System.out.print("_ ")
```

giving us an output of

"_ _ _ _ _ "

Lets say we guess the letter "O"
the letter "o" is guessed, how do i replace `

```
"_ _ _ _ _" with 
"_ _ o _ _ "
```

my current class file

```
public void pickWord()
    {
        String[] listOfWords;
        listOfWords = new String[10];
        listOfWords[0] = "shenanigans";
        listOfWords[1] = "conversely";
        listOfWords[2] = "octopus";
        listOfWords[3] = "dizzy";
        listOfWords[4] = "malicious";
        listOfWords[5] = "goosebumps";
        listOfWords[6] = "flying";
        listOfWords[7] = "staff";
        listOfWords[8] = "xylophone";
        listOfWords[9] = "zapping";
        Random generator = new Random();
        int lineNumber = generator.nextInt(9);
        disguisedWord = listOfWords[lineNumber];


    }   
    public void displayMark()
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < disguisedWord.length(); i ++)
            underscore = underscore + "_ ";
        System.out.println(underscore);

    }
    public void makeGuess() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Your word is " + disguisedWord.length() + " letters long.");
        System.out.println("Feel free to guess a letter.");
        guess = (char)System.in.read();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String ghost = "ghost";
String input = "o";
for (int i = 0; i < ghost.length(); i++) {
    if (String.valueOf(ghost.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
        System.out.print(input + " ");
    } else {
        System.out.print("_ ");
    }
}
```

You can *simplify* the if statement using the ternary operator:

```
System.out.print(String.valueOf(ghost.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase(input) ? input + " " : "_ ");
```

Comment: should i replace my method displayMark with that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that would be to use a Java regular expression on the target word. So whenever a user types in a letter you look for that letter in a regex match. That match will give you back the index of matching characters which you can then use to replace the letter in the `__` version of the string.

```
...    
    listOfWords[9] = "zapping";
    Random generator = new Random();
    int lineNumber = generator.nextInt(9);
    disguisedWord = listOfWords[lineNumber];
    char[] hidden = disguisedWord.replaceAll("*","_").toCharArray();
}

public void makeGuess() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Your word is " + disguisedWord.length() + " letters long.");
    System.out.println("Feel free to guess a letter.");
    String guess = System.in.read();

    Pattern pat = new Pattern(guess);
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(disguisedWord);
    while (mat.find()) {
        int start = mat.start();
        hidden[start] = guess.toCharArray()[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to use regex to find index of a character, this function is already in the `String` API.

Comment: imagine its 5 am and im a college freshman who knows very little about the regex matching

where do i put pattern pat = new pattern

or are you referring to my code ?
sorry for  my ignorance ^_^

Comment: @LeeHurlbert I am referring to your code. You put the `Pattern` after each guess from the user

Answer (score 0):

Why not have another array of true/false values that mark what letters have been guessed and what letters are still unknown? I don't think using regex and string replaces is an easy way to go about getting hangman to work, especially when they guess another letter.

Something like this perhaps.

```
String answer = "someword";
boolean[] knownLetters = new boolean[answer.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++) {
    if(knownLetters[i]) {
        System.out.print(answer.charAt(i));
    } else {
        System.out.print("_");
    }
}
System.out.println("");
```

Comment: would i replace my method display mark with this ^_^?

and is "string answer = "someword"
the randomized word?

Comment: Sure, I guess. I mean, you could probably wrap this in a method and just pass answer as a parameter, as well as move the the knownLetters array to an outer scope so that other methods and wherever else you may need it can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easy way would be storing the state in a variable and by looping over the real world replace the matching characters.

```
private String word; 
private char[] state;

public void guess(char input){
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == input){
            state[i] = word.charAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

afterwards you can print the contents of "state".