# im trying to replace a char in a string

Tags: java, string, replace, char, stringbuilder

My program is guessing a word. I have 2 strings `wordToGuess` - the word the user should guess and
`wordSoFar` - the word the user see with `_ _ _`.

When he guess a letter, the `_` changes to that letter.
I tried to use `substring` but it didn't work, so now I am trying use `stringBuilder` and it doesn't work while running.

```
public String showLetter(char letter) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(wordSoFar);

    for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++) {
        if (wordToGuess.charAt(i) == letter) {
            sb.setCharAt(i, letter); 
        }
     }

    return sb;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work while running". What errors do you have? I can immediately see a compile error as you are trying to return the StringBuilder instead of a String. Change the last line to `return sb.toString();`.

Comment: or you can change the return type on method header to become `StringBuilder`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java replacement of specific characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341581/java-replacement-of-specific-characters) or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288055/replacing-letters-in-words-for-hangman-error or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474223/java-replace-a-character-in-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a StringBuilder for this:

```
String wordSoFar = "_ _ _ _ _";
String wordAfterGuess = wordSoFar.substring(0,4)+'x'+wordSoFar.substring(5);
```

This should result in "_ _ x _ _"

your total class could look like this:

```
public class test {

private static String wordToGuess = "quorum";
private static String wordSoFar = "______";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    wordSoFar = showLetter('r');
    System.err.println(wordSoFar);
    wordSoFar = showLetter('q');
    System.err.println(wordSoFar);
    wordSoFar = showLetter('m');
    System.err.println(wordSoFar);

}

public static String showLetter(char letter) {
    for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++) {
       if (wordToGuess.charAt(i) == letter) {
           wordSoFar = wordSoFar.substring(0,i)+letter+wordSoFar.substring(i+1); 
         }
     }
    return wordSoFar;
}
```

}

which gives the following output:

```
___r__
q__r__
q__r_m
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to return the `StringBuilder` object rather than the `String` object that your method specifies as a return type, and the two are completely different objects.

You can't cast a `StringBuilder` into a `String`, but you can output the contents of a `StringBuilder` as a `String` by using the `.toString()` method, appended to the end of your `return` statement, so it reads along the lines of `return sb.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

You are **overcomplicating** things. You need a data structure that stores char values; and that can be easily changed; and that can be turned into a string easily. A String or StringBuilder/Buffer is not a good data structure for this requirement (as you already figured: because a String object is immutable).

Thus, I suggest a different solution: simply do **not** use a String or Buffer as "data structure" for guessed characters.

Instead, do something like:

```
char guesseedChars = new char[x];
Arrays.fill(guesseedChars, '_');
```

initially (where x would be the length of the word to guess).

Now, when the user make a correct guess, you drop the _:

```
guesseedChars[index] = 'a'
```

In other words: you replace the "wildcard" _ with the correct letter.

And to print, you can use:

```
String currentContent = new String(guesseedChars)
```

during each loop; and print that String. Done.